# Using SwingEventMonitor to monitor other applications?

Tags: java, swing, jnlp, java-web-start

How do I use SwingEventMonitor to monitor mouse events in applications running in other JVMs?

The demo code I have can monitor mouse clicks in applications running within its own JVM, but applications started seperately or via jnlp are ignored.

How do I make sure Java loads my SwingEventMonitor app with every application, regardless of how its started (desktop or jnlp)

Comment: Java VisualVM, [jvisualvm](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html), which is included with the JDK, maybe an alternative.

Comment: A useful debugging aid, but not something I can run on an end users machine. We'd already looked into it, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504559/is-it-possible-to-have-a-mousemotionlistener-listen-to-all-system-mouse-motion-e), there are a couple of pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your monitor and create a `sever = ServerSocket(MONITOR_PORT)`. Then listen for incoming connections:

```
while (true) {
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    connectionCount++;
    // start a new monitor thread for this connection
}
```

*Note: SwingEventMonitor is not included anymore in JDK1.7, you may wish to push your own EventQueue. See [What happened to SwingEventMonitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314965/what-happend-to-swingeventmonitor)*